# I need a way to copy parts of a canvas somewhere else on the same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, getimagedata

I know this has already been asked, but many of the answers I found were inconclusive and the questions weren't exactly depictive of my specific problem.

All I need to do is a "select-copy-paste" on a canvas, something that would take very little time on Microsoft Paint, but is turning out to be extremely difficult in JS. The point is, I actually need to perform a couple thousand of those on images that are up to 12 thousand pixels in width/height, so doing it on Paint is not an option.

Here's the most basic example I could write, just to focus on the issue I'm having:

Here's the HTML body:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<img id="house" class="hidden" type="img/png" src="house.png"></img>
```

Here's the JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var house = document.getElementById("house");

    ctx.drawImage(house, 10, 10);
    var data = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 80, 80); // ERROR
    ctx.putImageData(data, 110, 10);
}
```

And (although I think it's irrelevant) here's the CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

The line I commented with "ERROR" throws the following:
`Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

A few important things to note are that all of these files are in my local directories (in a folder on my desktop, to be exact), so I'm not involved with any website or host or anything internet-dependent. Also, I'm not running any servers nor do I have any, therefore I cannot change any authorizations or CORS settings; after all, why would I have to? All I'm trying to do is copy and paste pixels.

I also tried to create 12k by 12k matrix of strings, where each string represents the pixel value of the image. This way I wouldn't have to use `getImageData` on the canvas, but I could work on the strings and change their values, except this doesn't work because I can't use `getImageData` on an image.

If anybody could enlighten me with a solution to this problem I'd be extremely thankful.

#### EDIT

I feel silly for not having tried it earlier, but I found an extremely simple solution: use Explorer instead of Chrome. Explorer doesn't throw any errors when calling `getImageData`.

Comment: The basic problem is the tainted canvas, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image . If you're hosting the page at your local drive system, and you're running the page with file protocol, that is most likely the source of the CORS problems. Hosting the page on local server should do in this case.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have already read that article (and not only that) but it doesn't actually tell me how to host my page on a local server. For instance, in the paragraph titled _"Web server configuration"_ it displays a code, but what do I need to do with that code? Do I need to save it as a file? And if so, where do I need to place that file? Is it an XML file? Or do I just copy the whole thing and paste it in my HTML? (that doesn't work, I already tried).

Comment: The point of my comment was, that you need a server, not necessarily a web server, but a local server. The CORS rules for the file protocol are different compared to http(s) protocol. File protocol is more sensitive on CORS issues.

Comment: The server configuration example in the MDN article is saved as a part of Apache's configuration file, which usually is named as "httpd.conf" and is stored in an installation dependent directory at your server, a local server or a web server. That snippet is meant to serve images allowing CORS, so that everybody on the internet (or in a local network) can use them e.g. in a canvas without tainting the canvas.

Comment: To copy part of a canvas, use `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 10, 10, 80, 80, 110, 10, 80, 80)` instead of getImagedata putimagedata